# Reusing the session of the thread with NHibernate

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, nhibernate, mvvm

I know several topics on the subject have been discussed, because I have been reading a lot to try to resolve my issue, but somehow they happen to not fulfill my needs (maybe for the lack of detail). Anyway, if you think some specific 'topic' might be useful, please link it.

I'm developing a desktop application with WPF (and MVVM) and I'm using NHibernate. After researching about possible ways to manage my session, I have decided to use the session-per-form approach. By this way, I think I can fully use the features of NHibernate like lazy-loading, cache and so on.
As I'm working with a database, I don't want to freeze my UI while I'm loading or saving my entities, so I thought I should use a dedicated thread (in each form, which I think simplifies the development) to handle the database interaction. The problem, though, is how I should 'reuse' the thread (supposing I have a session associated with that thread) to make my 'database calls'.

- I think I couldn't use TPL because I'm not guaranteed that the two tasks would run in the same thread (it's not even guaranteed that they will be run in different threads than the invoker)
- I would prefer to use session-per-form, as I have seen similar discussions that end by using session-per-conversation or something like that. But anyway, if you find that session-per-conversation would be better, please tell me (and hopefully explain why)
- Threads don't provide a way to directly run more than one method, so I think I would have to 'listen' for requests, but I'm still unsure if I really have to do this and how I would 'use' the session (and save it) only inside the thread.

EDIT:
Maybe I'm having this problem because I'm confusing thread-safety with something else. 
When the NHibernate documentation says that ISession instances are not thread-safe, does it means that I will (or could) get into trouble if two threads attempt to use it **at the same time**, right? In my case, if I use TPL, different threads could use the same session, but I wouldn't perform more than one operation in the same session at the same time. So, would I get into trouble in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

If I may make a suggestion, desktop applications are poorly suited to interact with the database directly. The communication is not encrypted and it's really easy for someone with even the slightest amount of know-how to grab the database password and begin messing with records using a SQL connection and corrupt your database.

It would be better to create a web service with authentication that stands between the desktop application and the database as you could create credentials for each person and every transaction would be forcibly subjected to your various business rules.

This would also take care of your threading issue as you would be able to create HTTP connections on another thread with little to no trouble concerning session management. A cookie value is likely all that would be required and RestSharp makes this fairly trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
The connections are made using SSL (with the server properly configured), so I don't think it is that problematic. 
On the other hand, creating a web service, though could be more secure, would imply redesigning pretty much of the application, and that's not a viable decision right now (the project must be finished ASAP).
Also, the program is meant for a small network, so it is a more controlled environment

Comment: "The connections are made using SSL (with the server properly configured), so I don't think it is that problematic" the password to the SQL server is still stored in the application correct? It's pretty easy to extract that kind of thing.

Comment: It will be user introduced, but yes, I have the option to store them (encrypted). BTW, I'm not using SQL Server, I'm using PostgreSQL :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had misunderstood the SQL server part. I thought you were talking about Microsoft's SQL Server, so please ignore that part